# Move site to subdomain

Tags: domain

I have inherited a situation where I have 2 WordPress websites on one domain. I would like to let the older site sit on a subdomain and make sure the newer website sits on the top domain. As a novice to the backend side of development can someone help?

The older website sits on `domain.org.uk/public`
The second sits on `dnomain.org.uk/dev`

Comment: You should start with the official documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress If you encounter s specific issue, then consider asking a question about that issue. Otherwise any answer to this question would just be reiterating a topic that's extensively documented elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

it's more a devops topic.

you will need to replace all occurences of the websites in your Database to the new URL's.
like `domain.org.uk/public` replaced with  `domain.org.uk`.
there is a nice wordpress plugin which can do this https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/.